# Change SkyDrive credentials under Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, onedrive

I'm logged-in with "newaccount@outlook.com" into Windows 8.1. It is a brand new account. I have an older one "oldaccount@live.com" which has free 25GB of skydrive. The new account offers 7GB, what I want to do is to "tell" the integrated Windows 8.1 SkyDrive app to use different credentials so it can connect with my old account not the new one. This way I'll get to see my files. Same as we do with dropbox, google drive, ubuntu one, etc

BTW, if this comes up, the new account is because I have changed countries and wanted to start from scratch with accounts. There is a whole mess with changing countries in MS accounts... so it is easier to create a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Each Skydrive account is tied to a single MS account, and you can't separate the login credentials used in 8.1 from the SkyDrive credentials.

From Windows 8 [SkyDrive: FAQ](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows-8/skydrive-app-faq):

> **Do I have to sign in to my PC with a Microsoft account to use SkyDrive?**
>
> Yes, you need to sign in with a Microsoft account to browse your
>   SkyDrive and keep your files and settings in sync. If you sign in with
>   a local account, you can only use the SkyDrive app to browse your PC.
>   To browse your SkyDrive files, you'll need to go to SkyDrive.com.

and

> **Can I sign in with a different account to browse a different SkyDrive?**
>
> You can't switch between accounts in the SkyDrive app. When you sign
>   in to a PC with your Microsoft account, you're automatically signed in
>   to SkyDrive with that account. You can still get to SkyDrive files for
>   a different account by going to SkyDrive.com.